# Finding the poles of a certain Zeta function

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, residue-calculus, zeta-functions

I'm interested in the following zeta function:

$$\zeta_D(s)=\sum_{(m,n)\in \mathbb N^2} \frac{1}{(m^2+n^2)^s}$$

Where naturally $(m,n)\neq (0,0)$. I'm mainly interested in its poles (so I can perform an integral [Mellin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform) on it later), and so I'm looking for a way to simplify this expression, or write it in terms of other functions who's poles I know well.

I tried to somehow use the [Hurwitz Zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function), but I didn't get too far with this approach. Another approach I had in mind is using the Poisson summation formula, and identifying the terms in the sum as Fourier coefficients of some sort, but I didn't get too far with this either.

Does anyone have an idea of what I can do in order to find the poles and residues? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $\sum_{(m,n)\ne (0,0)}(m^2+n^2)^{-s}$ is mermorphic on the whole complex plane with  only one simple pole at $s=1$

There are two approaches,

- one from the unique factorization in prime ideals in the PID $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ which leads to  $$\sum_{(m,n)\ne (0,0)}(m^2+n^2)^{-s}=4\zeta(s)L(s,\chi_4)$$
- and the other from $$\pi^{-s}\Gamma(s)\sum_{(m,n)\ne (0,0)}(m^2+n^2)^{-s}=\int_0^\infty (\theta(x)^2-1) x^{s-1}dx$$ where $\theta(x)=\sum_k e^{-\pi k^2 x}$ which is $=x^{-1/2}\theta(1/x)$ from the Poisson summation formula.

If you only care of the poles on $\Re(s)>1/2$ then the Gauss circle problem is the simplest solution.

Comment: Thank you! What is the function L(s,chi_4) (and what is chi_4)? I'm not familiar with it. Specifically, how can I find its value at s=0,1? And how did you get the given expression from the unique factorization in Z[i]? Guess this is some theorem I haven't heard of

Comment: it is the first non-trivial Dirichlet character $\chi_4(2n)=0,\chi_4(2n+1)=(-1)^n,L(s,\chi_4)=\sum_{n\ge 1} \chi_4(n)n^{-s}$. We show it is entire following the same methods as for $\eta(s)$.